# How can I obtain a permalink of our US Patent Document?

Tags: linking, permalink

The link we used on our website is broken now with the launch of USPTO’s Patent Public Search tool in February 2022. All the tips I find online how to create the link do not work.

Comment: USPTO's search page seems broken to me in Safari. It seems to work in Chrome, but I haven't found a permanent link function as yet.